# Maven profile activation with multiple conditions

Tags: maven-2, pom.xml

I'm working on getting the rpm-maven plugin setup in a project. In our staging and production environments, the build occurs on Red Hat boxes, but we have several Windows boxes that are used for development and testing so I wanted the RPM build process to be part of a profile that is only active on a box that has rpmbuild installed.

This was my first attempt at an activation condition:

```
<activation>
  <os>
    <family>unix</family>
  </os> 
  <file>
    <exists>/usr/bin/rpmbuild</exists>
  </file>
</activation>
```

My initial testing only involved building on a Windows box and building on a CentOS box, and both gave me the results I expected. Later, the build broke on a Linux machine that didn't have rpmbuild available. It looks like having two conditions like this isn't supported. Is this the case? I realize I can probably just get rid of the `<os/>` element and get the results I want, but for future reference is there a better way to create profiles with multiple activation conditions?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Maven `<activation>` block is a list of `OR` -- the profile will be activated as soon as the first criteria is met. So, it is less likely that your problem has a solution at least until this bug-report gets fixed https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MNG-4565

---

## Update:

it's fixed in 3.2.2 now –  sfussenegger (via comment)

Comment: @bhinks it does not make sense though. Sadly, Maven: the definitive guide says that it's behaviour should be `AND` -- but it is not.

Comment: since every search I have done on google pops up with this SO.  if you want to do an OR how do you do that?  for example I want to activate if they use the command -Ddeep-clean OR -Dlight-clean.
Is this no longer possible since 3.2.2?

Comment: @dtracers good question! how am I supposed to configure "OR" logic in this case. Maven changed the logic of processing properties and now it is not possible to do "OR". Fixing one issue - creating another one ?

Comment: @dtracers, the thing is, it was always an issue, that it should be working differently, now it's time to create issue, to allow make different activation things both OR and AND

Comment: @dtracers - I hope they'll go to a more robust syntax for activation conditions. A kludge in the mean time would be to put two profiles in the settings.xml, each with different activation (one for `-Ddeep-clean` and one for `-Dlight-clean`) and have each of those set a property (`light-clean-or-deep-clean`?) which you can use to activate a profile in the pom that can do the real configuration

Answer (score 18):

And worst you can mix condition of different type for example file, jdk and property as described here **http://www.sonatype.com/books/mvnref-book/reference/profiles-sect-activation.html**, but you can't even put two condition of same type, for example two properties

```
<activation>
    <property>
           <name>integrationTest</name>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>packaging</name>
        <value>swf</value>
    </property>
 </activation>
```

This won't work as only one `<property>` tag will be allowed.
Associated JIRA : https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MNG-3328

And the bug described above is still open... 5 years it's just a shame !

Comment: 7 years already! Just voted for it. Don't think it's going to change something.

Comment: 9 years and counting.

Comment: I have mostly given up on profile activation logic and just make a shell scripts that determine profiles to activate and then pass them to maven with `-P"someProfile,!someOtherProfile"` which makes the property and environment variable detection completely worthless.

Answer (score 14):

Just fixed by me :)

Starting from 3.2.2 it will work as expected: multiple conditions will be ANDed

Reference - https://github.com/apache/maven/commits/master, search by `MNG-4565`

Commit URL - https://github.com/apache/maven/commit/c6529932f9e3efdfc86ed73f59a307a8f8b6ea5f

Comment: Wish OR or AND were both options. Unfortunate that OR was just removed for AND.

Comment: @mdo123, that's probably how it should be done, yes. Should be a good idea to contribute it somehow to maven

Comment: Can you provide the actual commit URL (based on commit hash)? Now 3.5 years later it would be a lot of commits to trawl through!

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what these Maven extensions do:

- [Maven EL Profile Activator Extension](https://github.com/OndraZizka/el-profile-activator-extension/)

  This one is pretty simple, have a look at the [source](https://github.com/OndraZizka/el-profile-activator-extension/blob/master/src/main/java/com/redhat/jboss/maven/elprofile/ElProfileActivator.java)
- [Maven Profile Activation Extension](https://github.com/random-maven/profile-activator-extension/)

  This one has [more options for the actual activation expression](https://github.com/random-maven/profile-activator-extension/tree/master/src/main/java/com/carrotgarden/maven/activator), including Scala.

**However**, since it's an extension (not a plugin), every project using it will have to register the extension. And there's a risk that the project author will abandon it and it won't work in future maven versions.